# jQuery Moblile panel doesn't push page over

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make a side menu panel that is hidden by default. If the menu button is hit the page slides revealing the hidden menu. Sort of facebook-ish. The problem I'm having is that the menu will appear but only the header-bar is pushed over not the rest of the page.

Here is the html pastebin: http://pastebin.com/zyEU6mb7 and the CSS: http://pastebin.com/yFHzdMU1

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page contents should go under a div with `data-role="content"`

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7dvuR/)**

```
<div data-role="content">
 <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" id="homepageAccordian">
  <!-- Crew List -->
   <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Crew</h3>
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
        <li>Crew #1</li>
        <li>Crew #2</li>
        <li>Crew #3</li>
        <li>Crew #4</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- Last Ten -->
      <div data-role="collapsible">
       <h3>Open Calls</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
         <li>Call #1</li>
         <li>Call #2</li>
         <li>Call #3</li>
         <li>Call #4</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep that fixed it! Thanks for the help. Totally forgot to do that.